# Equation of a plane from 2 lines

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, plane-curves

I have two lines with the following equation

> $$D1 : (x, y, z) = (2,0,0) + k(0,3,0)$$
>       $$D2 : (x, y, z) = (2,0,2) + k(0,0,1)$$

and I must find out the equation of the plane that they make. I made a quick visual representation of the two lines, and if I'm right they don't cross. There's one that goes straight vertical and the other one is parallel to the axis of Z.

Is an equation still possible or it's a trap issue?

Comment: They do intersect.  Take another look.

Comment: @bob.sacamento It's been 1 hour that I'm looking at it, I don't get it. What's the intersection?

Comment: They intersect at (2,0,0) =(2,0,0) + 0 (0,3,0) = (2,0,2) - 2 (0,0,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of any plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by $$\overrightarrow{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\overrightarrow{\mathbf{x}}=\overrightarrow{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\overrightarrow{\mathbf{p}}$$ where

1. $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{n}}$ is a vector orthogonal to the plane
2. $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{x}}=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$
3. $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{p}}$ is a point on the plane

The data you give is sufficient to construct $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{n}}$ and $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{p}}$. Indeed we may take $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{n}}=(0,3,0)\times(0,0,1)=(3,0,0)$ and $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{p}}=(2,0,0)$. Thus our equation becomes $3x=6$.
The equation of our plane is then
$
x=2
$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To see if they intersect,
you want
$(2,0,0) + a(0,3,0)
=(2,0,2) + b(0,0,1)
$
for some real
$a$ and $b$.

This is,
looking at the ordinates,

$\begin{array}\\
2
&= 2\\
0+3a
&=0\\
0
&=2+b\\
\end{array}
$

These give
$a=0, b=-2$,
so they intersect at
$(2, 0, 0)$.